# Listing Active Members of Current Group in View pane (OG 7.x-2.3)

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am relatively new to Drupal and somewhat boggled by the new version of Organic Groups. We recently migrated our site from OG 7.x-1.4 to OG 7.x-2.3. Everything went fine except certain view panes no longer work. We had one view content pane that listed the members of the group in a page based on the context. We created a panel page for the group home page layout when the content pane was embedded in that page it would show the members for that group. However, the contextual filter for that view was broken after the import.

I tried to copy the view settings from a clean install of the latest OG code but that didn't work. The view is one of users but I cannot figure out how I should set the contextual filters or the relationships of that view to show only the members of the group. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how the OG_Membership object works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrospect the answer was rather obvious. When you migrate from OG 1.x to OG 2.x, the views associated with OG do not get updated. So they have "missing/broken relationships." For most of the view panes it was easy to fix by going to the view page and under the "edit view name/description" drop down, there is an option to "Revert View". Choosing this fixes the views that come with OG because it "reverts" the view to the updated OG 2.x code. Custom views have to be rebuilt.